# sql query for woocommerce products

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

i want to write a sql query to get a list of all the products inserted in woocommerce with their price and attributes and their photo's.

here is my code so far

```
SELECT `ID`,`post_title`,`post_date`,`post_author` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`='product'
LEFT JOIN Orders ON wp_posts.ID = wp_wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id
```

when i enter this code i get these errors

```
Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 150)
Unexpected token. (near "wp_wc_product_meta_lookup" at position 152)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position 177)
Unexpected token. (near "product_id" at position 178)
```

can you guys help me with this ? i know it's something super simple but i'm noob in sql .

Comment: Your query has too many errors to fix.  It is referencing columns in tables not in the `FROM` clause.  The `SELECT` clauses are out of order.  The column names are potentially ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a custom query for this? Should be pretty easy using built-in function wc_get_products() which works similar to a regular loop: https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_products/

Comment: i want to move my products to another website that's why